# Inline error handling in composer templating has invalid conditional

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Versions: EE 2.9.0 & Freeform 4.2.0 Pro

Some help would be appreciated. :-)

I am trying to implement inline error handling in a Freeform Composer Template and it is throwing the error:

```
You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing }, or a missing {/if}. Parser State: Unexpected ‘:’ (MISC); expected RD in on line 17.
```

The line of code that throws the error is this

```
{if freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}
```

Which is copied from [your documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/composer/#freeform_error_field_name)

If I hard code in the field name like this:

```
{if freeform:error:first_name}
```

It works, I think. But I get an error for every field, even those not required.

Here is my complete Composer Template code

```
{composer:page}
{composer:rows}
        <div class="row">
            {composer:columns}
                <div class="columns {if composer:column_total == 2}six{if:elseif composer:column_total == 3}four{if:elseif composer:column_total == 4}three{if:else}twelve{/if}">
                    {if composer:field_total == 0}

                    {/if}
                {composer:fields}
                    {if composer:field_label}
                        {if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
                            {if freeform:captcha}
                            <p>
                                <strong>{composer:field_label}</strong>
                            </p>
                            {/if}
                        {if:else}
                            <label class="field_label" {if composer:field_name != ''}for="freeform_{composer:field_name}"{/if}>
                                {composer:field_label}{if composer:field_required}<span class="required_item">*</span>{/if}
                            </label>
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                    {if composer:field_output}
                        {if freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}
                            <strong>
                                Error: {freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}
                            </strong>
                        {/if}
                        {if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_title'}
                            <h2>{composer:field_output}</h2>
                        {if:elseif composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
                            {if freeform:captcha}
                                    {freeform:captcha}<br />
                                    <input type="text" name="captcha" value=""
                                           size="20"   maxlength="20" style="width:140px;" />
                            {/if}
                        {if:else}
                            {composer:field_output}
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                {/composer:fields}
                    </div><!-- end columns -->
            {/composer:columns}
        </div><!-- end row -->
{/composer:rows}
{/composer:page}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the lines

```
{if freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}
                        <strong>
                            Error: {freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}
                        </strong>{/if}
```

**TO**

```
{if "{freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}" != ""} 
                        <strong>
                            Error: {freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}
                        </strong>{/if}
```

in the Template code. That should work.

Comment: Thank you. I just spent 60 minutes and the inline form error processing is happening. I tried using the composer and freeform tags. Nothing. Something is up.

Comment: Today I revisited the issue and managed to get things working. I am not sure exactly what I did, but your code did help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that is working for us, based on enj fix. Thank you!

```
{composer:rows}
        <div class="row">
            {composer:columns}
                <div class="columns {if composer:column_total == 2}six{if:elseif composer:column_total == 3}four{if:elseif composer:column_total == 4}three{if:else}twelve{/if}">
                    {if composer:field_total == 0}

                    {/if}
                {composer:fields}
                    {if "{freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}" != ""}<span class="error">{/if}
                    {if composer:field_label}
                        {if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
                            {if freeform:captcha}
                            <p>
                                <strong>{composer:field_label}</strong>
                            </p>
                            {/if}
                        {if:else}
                            <label class="field_label" {if composer:field_name != ''}for="freeform_{composer:field_name}"{/if}>
                                {composer:field_label}{if composer:field_required}<span class="required_item">*</span>{/if}
                            </label>
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                    {if composer:field_output}

                        {if composer:field_type == 'nonfield_title'}
                            <h2>{composer:field_output}</h2>
                        {if:elseif composer:field_type == 'nonfield_captcha'}
                            {if freeform:captcha}
                                    {freeform:captcha}<br />
                                    <input type="text" name="captcha" value="" size="20" maxlength="20" style="width:140px;" />
                            {/if}
                        {if:else}
                            {composer:field_output}
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                    {if "{freeform:error:{composer:field_name}}" != ""}</span>{/if}
                {/composer:fields}
                    </div><!-- end columns -->
            {/composer:columns}
        </div><!-- end row -->
{/composer:rows}
```